# If $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ exists (converges), then $\int_a^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

This is a true or false statement:

If $\displaystyle \int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ exists (converges), then $\displaystyle\int_a^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ converges for $a>0$ (and $a\in\mathbb{R^+}$).

In first place I thought this was false, but tried a numerous amount of functions but none of them works as a counterexample. It also confuses me that $a>0$, since I'm not sure if an inegral where I take $a=10^{-50}$ (for instance) it should diverge if it's a "huge" number or not.

It might be true, but I can't prove it. Any hint?

PD: I don't know if working with bounded functions in the interval $[a,1]$ may also work.

Comment: Good point. I didn't consider that. I think you can construct a counterexample in that case.

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily positive. Bounding the integral from above doesn't mean that it converges.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's the criteria "if $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, then $\int_a^\infty g(x)dx<\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$, right?

Comment: I didn't tink about that @jvc, that would make the statement false? I'm confused to be honest

Comment: I don't get  kevinkayaks's comment. Assuming $f(x)\ $ is positive, $\ f(x) >  \frac{f(x)}{x}\ $ for $ x > 1\ $ only.

Comment: Hmm, if $f$ is continuous and $F$ is an antiderivative, then using integration by parts, $\int_a^R \frac{f(x)}{x}dx = \frac{F(R)}{R} - \frac{F(a)}{a} + \int_a^R \frac{F(x)}{x^2}dx$ and since $F$ is bounded, $\frac{F(R)}{R} \to 0$ as $R\to \infty$ and $\int_a^\infty \frac{F(x)}{x^2}dx$ converges (absolutely).  I wonder if then a density argument of some kind would extend the result to locally $L^1$ functions $f$.

Comment: The section on integrals [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) is relevant.

Comment: @DavidMitra it says a non-negative function, which this could be the case...

Comment: @DanielSchepler What is a $L^1$ function?

Comment: OK, based on that question I'm guessing you're not using the Lebesgue integral, in which case the question is moot and you're probably assuming from the start that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm using Riemann-Integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true if  the improper integral $\displaystyle\int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx$ is conditionally convergent, even if $f \not\in L^1([a,\infty))$ and $f$ is neither nonnegative nor nonpositive.

Note that  $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing.  By the [second mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals), for any $c_2 > c_1 > a$  there exists $\xi \in (c_1,c_2)$ such that

$$\int_{c_1}^{c_2}\frac{f(x)}{x} \, dx = \frac{1}{c_1} \int_{c_1}^\xi f(x) \, dx,$$

and

$$\left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2}\frac{f(x)}{x} \, dx\right| = \frac{1}{c_1} \left|\int_{c_1}^\xi f(x) \, dx\right|\leqslant \frac{1}{a} \left|\int_{c_1}^\xi f(x) \, dx\right| $$

Since the improper integral of $f$ converges, it follows by the Cauchy criterion that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $C(\epsilon)> a$ such that for all $\xi > c_1 > C(\epsilon)$,
$$ \left|\int_{c_1}^\xi f(x) \, dx\right|< a\epsilon$$

Thus, for all $c_2> c_1 > C(\epsilon)$, we have

$$\left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2}\frac{f(x)}{x} \, dx\right| < \epsilon,$$

and $\displaystyle\int_a^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x} \, dx$ is convergent.

Comment: Brilliant. I keep forgetting the second mean value theorem for integrals but is it ever nice.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that $f \in L^1(a, \infty)$. By integration by part :

$$\int_a^\infty f(t) \frac1t dt = \Big[ \int_a^t f(u) du \times \frac1t \Big]_{t = a}^{t = \infty} + \int_a^\infty \int_a^t f(u) du \frac1{t^2} dt $$

Because $t \to |\int_a^t f(u) du| $ converges to a finite limite as $t \to \infty$ it is bounded by $M > 0$.

Thus :

$$\int_a^\infty f(t) \frac1t dt = 0 - 0 + \int_a^\infty \int_a^t f(u) du \frac1{t^2} dt $$

And :
$$| \int_a^t f(u) du \frac1{t^2} | \leq M \frac1{t^2} \in L^1(a, \infty)$$

Hence $\int_a^\infty \int_a^t f(u) du \frac1{t^2} dt$ converges.

I don't know if the result is still true when $f$ isn't in $L^1(a, \infty)$.

Comment: You can actually bypass a lot of this if you assume $f$ is absolutely integrable as you've done by mimicking what the other answer did.

Comment: You are right. I may be wrong, but my argument may be valid for $L^1_{loc}$ functions (using Fubini theorem to prove the IBP).